# How can I write pieces of a list into my .csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In my computer science class - Year 9 Computer Science, we're doing a project on writing into a .csv file using information that the user has input himself. The code I'm using should explain what I'm trying to do, but I'm ever so confused, because there's no output in the .csv file. I think it's because I tried taking the information from the list and putting it into the .csv file, I probably haven't done it correctly, but any help would be great. Also, don't completely change the code with some more advanced stuff than the things I'm doing here as I put most of my knowledge with python in to making this code.

```
import csv
import os

n = 10

names = list()
timeonstage = list()
moneypayed = list()

menu = input('Would you like to make a new table (New) or edit an existing    one(Edit)?')
if menu == 'New':


    for i in range(0, n):
        names.append(input('Please enter the name of the artist you would like to add: '))
    print(names)

    for i in range(0, n):
        timeonstage.append(input('Please enter how much time the actor is on     stage for: '))
    print(timeonstage)

    for i in range(0, n):
         moneypayed.append(input('Please enter how much money is being payed to    the actor: '))
    print(moneypayed)

    os.remove('MFP.csv')

    f = open('MFP.csv', 'a+')

    write1 = names[0]+','+timeonstage[0]+','+moneypayed[0]
    write2 = names[1]+','+timeonstage[1]+','+moneypayed[1]
    write3 = names[2]+','+timeonstage[2]+','+moneypayed[2]
    write4 = names[3]+','+timeonstage[3]+','+moneypayed[3]
    write5 = names[4]+','+timeonstage[4]+','+moneypayed[4]
    write6 = names[5]+','+timeonstage[5]+','+moneypayed[5]
    write7 = names[6]+','+timeonstage[6]+','+moneypayed[6]
    write8 = names[7]+','+timeonstage[7]+','+moneypayed[7]
    write9 = names[8]+','+timeonstage[8]+','+moneypayed[8]
    write10 = names[9]+','+timeonstage[9]+','+moneypayed[9]
    columns = 'Name of artist:'+','+'Artists time on stage:'+','+'Money        being payed:'

    f.write(str(columns))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write1))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write2))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write3))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write4))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write5))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write6))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write7))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write8))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write9))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(write10))
    f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done here is not closed the new `CSV` file when you have finished editing it therefore python doesn't know to save your edits. closing a file can be easily done by adding `f.close()` to the end of your code.

> When you’re done with a file, call f.close() to close it and free up
>   any system resources taken up by the open file. After calling
>   f.close(), attempts to use the file object will automatically fail.

(from https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: Thank you very much, should've seen that from the start.

Comment: @BlizzardGizzard Its fine we all make stupid mistakes